# Proper domain model design

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

1. Given an `Employee` entity and bunch of personal/organization-related information (like *marital status*, *children information*, *department*, *position*). Is all personal information to be represented as components/value objects or it is better for the information to reside inside the entity class?
2. Would using a person (which could gather all personal info) *value object* as an underlying object (`composition`) for an `Employee` entity be a bad design choice?
3. Also how would such a behaviour modelled properly (in terms of `DDD`): `If employee has kids then it should have a birth certificate (with corresponding data: name, issue date, etc)` or `If employee is married then it should have marriage certificate (with corresponding data: spouse name, etc)`?

For a kids case I decided to use `ChildrenInformation` value object:

```
public class ChildrenInformation
{
    public String BirthCertificateCode { get;set; }
    public DateTime BirthCertificateIssueDate { get;set; }
    public ChildName { get; set; }
    public ChildMiddleName { get; set; }
    public ChildLastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChildBirthday{ get; set; }
}

public class Employee : AbstractEntity<Employee>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public ISet<ChildrenInformation> ChildrenInformation { get; set; }

    /* other things ...*/
}
```

Wouldn't it be wrong from a design view?

**EDIT**

Another thought is to share `Certificate` class.

```
[Serializable]
public class Certificate
{
    public String Code { get; set; }
    public String Number { get; set; }
    public String RegistreeName { get; set; }
    public Address RegistreeAddress { get; set; }
    public String RegistreeDateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public String RegistredAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRegistred { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Employee : AbstractEntity<Employee>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Certificate Passport { get; set; }
    public Certificate MarriageCertificate { get; set; }
    public ISet<Certificate> ChildrenBirthCertificates { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about common law marriages? It is possible that they may not have a Marriage Certificate but their "Marriage" my still qualify as a domestic partnership.

Comment: @MarkKram domestic relationships are not considered here.

Answer (score 4):

I would model it like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String MiddleName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public BirthCertificate BirthCertificate { get;set; }
    public MarriageCertificate MarriageCertificate { get;set; }
    // ...etc...
}

public class Certificate
{
    public String Code { get;set; }
    public DateTime IssueDate { get;set; }
    // ...etc...
}

public class BirthCertificate: Certificate
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get;set; }
    // ...etc...
}

public class MarriageCertificate: Certificate
{
    public String SpouseName { get;set; } // or Spouse could also be a person
    // ...etc...
}

public class Employee
{
    public ISet<Person> Children { get; }
    // ...etc...
}
```

Some points:

- Note the ? usage which means certificates are optional.
- Certificate deserve their own types. If you have more than one property that start with the same prefix, most of the time, it means you can define an object off them. I have also created a base Certificate class because they may share some common properties and behavior.
- Children is a collection of Person objects.
- Spouse could also be a person, if you will (the property would then be named Spouse).
- I don't repeat the declaring type name in a property name: Name instead of PersonName

Comment: good note about certificate! Thanks. It seems to me that it is better to avoid using the person class? Holding cerificates inside a person class makes it unavoidable to use a composition of a person which corresponds to the employee or use an inheritance because Employee should expose its marital status. I'm confused with the design because of the dependency between states married/not-married and certificates presence..

Comment: Certificate could be null/optional since it's a reference type.

Comment: @helicera - good point :-) I had originally a struct in mind for certificates, but it does support derivates. I have updated my answer and removed the ?.

Comment: Ok) I'm going to use `Fluent validation` framework therefore I (if composition of person is chosen) must expose `Person` as a public property to validate employee-descendant properties. Also `Certificate` above conatins only several common properties, but no fuctionality. So it is kinda useless, except the situation when there are to many properties to share. I tried to simplify the design you proposed using only one `Certificate` class. *See edit*. But I dont think it's a good solution either. Help!)

Answer (score 0):

> Given an Employee entity and bunch of personal/organization-related information (like marital status, children information, department, position). Is all personal information to be represented as components/value objects or it is better for the information to reside inside the entity class?

I would put all of the given examples as properties in the employee entity. I don't see any benefit in having them as value objects?

> Would using a person (which could gather all personal info) value object as an underlying object (composition) for an Employee entity be a bad design choice?

This is more of a domain question. I normally do not use inheritance but use Customer and Employee (instead of a Person entity) as to different models not related to each other.

Comment: Ok! Then how do I model such a behavior? `If employee is married then it should have a certificate (which contains code, date, spouse name, age possibly)` or `If employee has kids then it must have certificate per kid` and again the last mentioned certificate should contain names, birthdays date, etc. So I decided to use something like `ChildrenInformation` v/o. Then employee could hold as much `ChildrenInformation` objects (as a set) as much kids it has. Isn't it wrong?

Comment: That information should have been in the question since DDD solutions aren't general but always modeled after the specific domain. Update the question and add all relevant information for the problem. You should probably add the homework tag too.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the design concept of composition has nothing to do with the CLR concept of a value type. Composition just means that the life-time of the owned object is bound to the life-time of the owner. This can also be achieved with reference types, for example if the owner is the only one with a reference to the owned object.

That said, the solution from Simon is just fine.